# C# array available outside function

Tags: c#, arrays, public

```
  private void frmExecute_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\toyotoconsole\\tssetup.txt");

        // Loop through each line, split, add if server
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
                var serverValues = data[i].Split('|');
        }
    }
```

Okay first C# windows project, which is cool since I have never really touched this beyond the odd debugging foray.

My problem is the array `serverValues` is built in a function, how do I make this array *available* for *all functions* (not sure if using the right term here) in the same form script (probably the wrong word there as well). Is there a `public` declaration?

Comment: Turn *local variable* `serverValues` into a *field*: declare it outside: `private string[] serverValues = null; ... private void frmExecute_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {...serverValues = data[i].Split('|');...}`

Comment: Even though you turn it as a local variable, variable will overwrite everytime, so at last your `serverValues` will contain only value of `data[data.length - 1].Split('|')`

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you should turn local *variable* `serverValues` into a *field* (or *property*):

```
  private string[] serverValues = new string[0];

  private void frmExecute_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
    serverValues = data[i].Split('|'); 
    ...
  }
```

However, as one can see, you *rewrite* `serverValues` within the loop; that's why `serverValues` will contain the *last* line splitted only. Another issue is mixing *Business logic* (`ServerValues`) and *UI* (form loading).

It seems you want something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private string[] m_ServerValues = null;

// Pure buiness logic: ServerValues without any UI (form)
public string[] ServerValues {
  get { 
    // If we have the array we return it
    if (m_ServerValues != null)
      return m_ServerValues;

    // otherwise we compute it
    m_ServerValues = File
      .ReadLines("c:\\toyotoconsole\\tssetup.txt")
      .SelectMany(line => line.Split('|'))
      .ToArray();

    // And return it
    return m_ServerValues;
  } 
}

// UI: form loading
private void frmExecute_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // If you want to prefetch (it's not necessary)
  var values = ServerValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare a private property in you class 
private serverValues = Array.Empty<string>();
```

And then use within any event

```
private void frmExecute_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\toyotoconsole\\tssetup.txt");

    // Loop through each line, split, add if server
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        serverValues = data[i].Split('|');
    }
}
```

Comment: `private string[] severValues = new string[0];`: typo (`severValues`'s type)

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko, Upvoting your detailed answer